# For loop within for loop with ArcPy cursor?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, for-loop

Below mentioned one is a part of my script.This is working when I assinged numbers for f.(Instead of "f" I have substitute 2.Then it is working).But i want to run this based on the no of rows of the table named "TL"(f).Can any one suggest a method to do this?

```
f=arcpy.GetCount_management(TL)
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(PCL_Info, ['PCL_PG_ID','PCL_IF_LN','PCL_IF_CN','PCL_IF_RM','PCL_IF_LU','PCL_IF_EL','globalid','created_user','created_date','last_edited_user','last_edited_date','adm_gn_ix']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        for x in range(0,f):
           if(row[0] ==  parcel_ID[x]):
               c.append(row[0])
               c.append(row[1])
               c.append(row[2])
```

Comment: BERA's answer will solve your problem, but this double loop will be quite inefficient. It would probably work better with a dictionnary.

Comment: Hard to tell since we dont know what parcel_ID or c is, or the size of TL. parcel_ID could be a dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
f=arcpy.GetCount_management(TL)
```

To:

```
f=int(arcpy.GetCount_management(TL).getOutput(0))
```

Without getOutput, f is a [Result object](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/result.htm), not the actual count.

Example:

```
import arcpy
fc = r"C:\Test\Buildings.shp"
arcpy.GetCount_management(fc)
<Result '9'>
arcpy.GetCount_management(fc).getOutput(0)
'9'
int(arcpy.GetCount_management(fc).getOutput(0))
9
```